# When a local lambda is being captured by another lambda, should it be by value or by reference?

Tags: c++, lambda

I have a function that declares some local lambda variables, and wish to compose them in another lambda.  A simple example:

```
auto aggressiveModel = [this](const Params& params) -> double { ... };
auto lazyModel = [this](const Params& params) -> double { ... };
auto model = [ ((???))aggressiveModel, ((???))lazyModel](const Params& params) { return std::min(aggressiveModel(params), lazyModel(params)); };
```

In the `model(...)` lambda, should the other lambas be capture by value, reference, or default?  What do the specifiers mean in the context of lamba variables?

Comment: Are you going to be returning `model` out of the scope it is declared in?

Comment: @NathanOliver In this case no, but I am looking for more general guidance to understand what captures mean in the context of lambas.

Comment: Then in this case I would suggest capturing by reference.  In general though, if the lambda can outlive what you capture by reference, then you should be capturing by value, otherwise you could have a dangling reference.

Comment: They mean the exact same thing they mean in the context of not-lambdas. Lambdas aren't special.

Comment: A capturing lambda is actually an object being the scenes, think of it that way.  The same scoping and lifetime rules apply.

Comment: There is no "general guidance" on this, any more than there is a "general guidance" on any other complicated aspect of C++. The only kind of "general guidance" would be: understand the difference between the two, and how they work, and then make a decision every individual case based on those factors.

Comment: The answer is not particular to lambdas.  You are effectively asking "When an object has a member variable, should it be a value or reference?"  And the answer is "Do what is appropriate.  Reference variables have a purpose.  Non-reference variables also have a purpose."

Answer (score 1):

Lambdas are just simpler ways of writing old-style object functors. `aggressiveModel` is equivalent to:

```
struct AggressiveModel
{
  AggressiveModel(Object* _this)
  : _this(_this)
  {
  }

  Object* _this;

  double operator()(const Params& params)
  {
    ...
  }
};

AggressiveModel aggressiveModel(this);
```

copying `aggressiveModel` is therefore just a question of copying the captured `this` variable and not something you should worry about. Obviously a lambda with a longer capture list or that captures objects which are more expensive to copy would be different. Though even in that case the compiler may be able to optimise away the copies, especially if the lambda is not `mutable` and the compiler therefore knows none of the values will change and it can prove the original lambda doesn't go out of scope.

As with any other object, taking a reference to a lambda will avoid copying but you have to ensure that the object remains in scope for the lifetime of the reference.